# How to find optimal road path of multiple locations within a map by giving post codes as input?

Tags: c#, google-maps, routes

I've a requirement in which i **need to show optimal road route related to a fixed location** within a map by giving few **postcodes**, fetched from database on the basis of some conditions, as **input**.

The route should be shown as the least distanced postcode first order from the fixed location.

How can i implement using asp.net?

Can i use Google-map api to implement this?

Comment: Do you have access to a database of roads?

Comment: If you use Google maps, please note that according to §9 of their license terms, you must make your application **publicly available free of charge**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Google's database of roads, you have their API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?parameters
```

Their API is very well documented, so checking that out would be a great start. The output is available in XML and JSON, and it includes the waypoints which you are looking for.